# NavigationDrawer и клавиатура

Tags: java, android

Во время нажатия на EditText появляется клавиатура, но когда открываем NavigationDrawer то она никуда не пропадает и даже если перейдем на другой фрагмент без EditText'а который был нажат в начале,клавиатура остается. Как можно отследить открыт ли NavigationDrawer?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуй этот код:

```
DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
drawer.setDrawerListener(new DrawerLayout.DrawerListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) BaseActivity.this.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(BaseActivity.this.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerStateChanged(int newState) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло,  добавил только сразу в ActionBarDrawerToggle